# Ударение в фамилии Майринк

Tags: орфоэпия, фамилии

Нашла что-то только на этом сайте: https://how-to-all.com/%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA. Рекомендуют ставить ударение на второй слог, но мне их вариант представляется сомнительным. Я бы по аналогии с настоящей фамилией писателя поставила бы ударение на первый слог (в оригинале: Meyer — Meyrink, Мéйер — Мáйринк), да и сам источник не из авторитетных. Наконец, в немецком языке больше фамилий, мне кажется, с ударением на первый слог. В общем, подскажите, кто знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если место ударения в иностранной фамилии нельзя узнать от носителя фамилии или из словаря, стоит руководствоваться тем, на какой слог падает ударение в языке носителя.

Гу́став Мáйринк — так следует произносить фамилию известного австрийского писателя, исходя из немецкой транскрипции.